# C++ Email/SMTP

Tags: c++, windows, email, visual-c++, smtp

Hey, Can you recommend me what C++ library or classes are available for sending email via SMTP in C++. I'm on Windows platform. I need a library which supports attachments and SSL connections. What are the options available. I'm not into implementing my own :)

Regards

EDIT: Oh I forgot to mention I'm using Visual C++ 6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%2B%2B++SMTP

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ SMTP Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example)

Answer (score 1):

I found a project that might be what you're looking for: [lib smtp](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/libsmtp/).

Comment: Well, I need one which supports attachments and SSL connection.

Comment: Yep, that is true... Looking at its API I hoped that it would have callbacks so that you could chain it with something like OpenSSL and do encryption that way, but that doesn't seem to exist. You can still modify it to do that, as it's open source. There are other projects that on the surface look better (libsmtp++, libsmtp--), but those appear dead. Hopefully you can find a project that is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with the [ATL class CSMTPConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt90h0a7(VS.80).aspx), but I don't think it supports SSL.

Comment: Yes, I have found few but they don't support SSL too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ultimate-TCP/IP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateTCPIP.aspx), free on Code Project - it includes support for SMTP and you can just compile in the parts you want.  It's very good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any library. (never on Windows)
Just use Winsock or COM

Comment: Well as I mentioned in my post, "I'm not into implementing my own :)"


Thanks